# Bootstrap Grid not scaling on tablets,

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an Angular/Bootstrap web app, and I'm having some curious behaviour from tablets.

I have a set of 9 pills/tabs in the content, each with `col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3` set in their class. So basically, they remain in a single line when on most desktop-sized screens, 2 lines on most tablet screens, and a 3x3 grid on most phone screens.

This is behaving normally when testing with Chrome, IE, and Firefox on my desktop (Windows 7), as well as on my HTC One.

However, when testing on any iOS device, Safari on my desktop, or even a Lenovo android tablet, every tab is listing vertically, no matter what screen size.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Could you post the html of that section?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops; figured it out. I was using display:inline-flex;
I guess I should really read up more on browser compatibilities...